# How to get all the sharepoint 2013 site users using csom javascript

Tags: 2013, javascript, user, csom

I know how to get all users in share point site by using c# code ,but i want to get all site users using csom javscript.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Just make a ajax request to the following url, and it will give you all site users

```
/_api/web/siteusers
```

**Full code using rest API**

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/siteusers",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.d.results);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

**Full code using csom javascript**

```
function GetAllUsers() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var web = clientContext.get_web();

    var userInfoList = web.get_siteUserInfoList();

    this.collListItem = userInfoList.getItems();

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var item = collListItem.itemAt(0);

    var profileNotes = item.get_item(‘Notes’);
    alert(profileNotes);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {}
}
```

Above code taken from [here](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2011/10/15/retrieve-all-user-in-sharepoint-2010-site-using-javascript-client-object-model/)

Comment: sandbox solutions it is posible?

Comment: Yup ...... Make sure jquery is in your page

Comment: Hi There,
Mine is SP 2010

on tyring this script i am getting below error.
"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UnknownError"

It goes in error call back

Comment: I got the same problem like shoab on SP 2013. Does nobody has an answer to this?